# Redirecting whole website to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I recently build a website and installed my SSL certificate and all that, but my website is still showing up as non-certified and unsafe, the reason is that because the website is still using HTTP address, and not HTTPS, i found my `.htaccess` file, and this is what it has inside:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
```

I found that in order to redirect to HTTPS, I need to use this:

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

and that works, only thing is that only works for the main page, the "homepage" if you try to open any other page of the website it shows a 404 message not found, so my question is:

What do i need to do in order to redirect my WHOLE DOMAIN, to use HTTPS so i can display the "PADLOCK AND SSL CERTIFICATE" on the URL bar?

Comment: 404 before redirection or after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add https to a wordpress site that has a `valid` cert your rules should look like this. You also need to use `[R=301,L]` at the end of the rule. If you don't specify which `R` status code it defaults to `302`, which is temporary. You want `301` for permanent. You need to also use the `L` with the redirect to prevent things like `404`. Read the bottom note.

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   # BEGIN WordPress
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

From the documentation.

> You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that
>   is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends
>   http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the
>   next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in
>   request' warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I found this great article about [How to Move a WordPress Website from HTTP to HTTPS/SSL](http://designmodo.com/wordpress-https/).  At the end of the article, it gives instructions for setting up a permanent 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS by adding the following code to the top of WordPress’ .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Replace every instance of `yoursite.com` with the URL for your WordPress site.

I recommend that you go through the **entire** webpage I gave above and make sure you follow the steps exactly as listed.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help guys! i'd vote up the answers but i got less than 15 rep so i can't, anyways, i followed the guide Tim Biegeleisen suggested, although i couldn't get the 301 redirects to work by modifying the .htaccess file, i got the website to run using HTTPS, so now it shows the padlock and ssl certificate, when i modified the .htaccess file as suggested i couldn't access the website, google said that "it had too many redirect loops" so i just left the .htaccess with the default code on it, and what i did was to go to the wordpress panel and modified the  **WordPress Address** (URL) and **Site Address** (URL) are using https, after that i added my website to the google webmaster tools, and i think that closed the circle and now works great, so far so good! thanks for your help guys!